# How can a samza task consume more than one kafka partitioned streams

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, apache-samza

I have a typical samza task which consumes 2 topics: `data` and `config`, and stores messages from `config` as local state in rocksdb to check if messages from `data` are OK.

This task works fine if each of these two topics has only one partition. Once I split `data` into ten partitions and `config` remains one partition, things changed. By default, samza creates ten tasks to consume partition 0 ~ 9 of `data` topic and only task 0 consumes `config` topic:

`task[0] -> config, data[0]
task[1] -> data[1]
...
task[9] -> data[9]`

It seems each task is initialized with its own rocksdb instance, so only task[0] stores all the config data in its rocksdb instance, task[1~9] has no config data and hence unable to find config information of the incoming data.

What I expected is each task consumes messages from its data partition and the config stream like this:

`task[0] -> config, data[0]
task[1] -> config, data[1]
...
task[9] -> config, data[9]`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution of input stream(s)'s partition is governed by a pluggable grouper that is configured using "job.systemstreampartition.grouper.factor". By default, This class groups the incoming stream partitions across tasks instances. By default, I believe it does a GroupByPartitionId. That is why you are seeing data[0] and config[0] in task[0].

You can implement a custom SSPGrouper. However, what you are looking for is to treat "data" stream as a regular input stream and "config" stream as a "**broadcast**" input stream. Broadcast means every task in the Samza job reads from this stream's partitions. This way, each task instance can populate its local rocksdb with config streams' data. You can configure broadcast streams as:
`task.broadcast.inputs=<systemName>.<streamName>#[<partition-range>], <systemName>.<streamName>#[<partition-range>]`

For your case, you can configure:
`task.inputs = <systemName>.data
task.broadcast.inputs = <systemName>.config#0`

Check out [Broadcast Streams in Samza](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.10/container/samza-container.html)

Comment: According to @NavinaRamesh 's suggestion, I encountered an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: incorrect format in kafka.config#[0]. Broadcast stream names should be in the form 'system.stream#partitionId' or 'system.stream#[partitionN-partitionM]'`, which means the correct format should be `task.broadcast.inputs = <systemName>.config#0`, and after I changed to the correct format, everything works like a charm. Thanks and cheers, @NavinaRamesh :)

Comment: Glad  you were able to figure it out :) I have fixed the config format in my response. Thanks!